# Arduino: pass function to class, returning String

Tags: c++, string, arduino

I'm trying to get my Arduino class to return String messages with all kind of information for logging. With lots of trial and error I manage to pass a reference to the logging function to the class, but can only get a char* but not a String, and I want to be able to send Strings making it so much easier to send back all kinds of data.

I have the first part working already.
The sketch:

```
#include <Test.h>
#include <string.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Test t;
  t.setLogging(writeLog);
  writeLog("Test message!" + String(" .... "));
  t.doSomething("This is useful.");
  t.doSomething("This as well.\n");
  t.doSomething("This is even more useful.\n");
  bool b = true;

}

void loop() {
}

void writeLog (char* message) {
  Serial.print("char function: ");
  Serial.print(message);
}

void writeLog (String message) {
  Serial.print("String function: ");
  Serial.println(message);
}
```

The header file:

```
#ifndef TEST_h
#define TEST_h

class Test
{
  public:
    Test();       // The constructor.
    void setLogging(void (*)(char*)); // Takes function setting where to log.
    void doSomething(char*);
};

#endif
```

The class:

```
#include <Test.h>

typedef void (*LogFunction)(char*);
LogFunction writeLog;

Test::Test () { 
}

void Test::doSomething (char* s) {

  // Do something useful and log the result.
  writeLog(s);
}

void Test::setLogging (void (*f)(char*) ) {
  writeLog = f;
  return;
}
```

Now what I want my class to be able to do is send information like this, as String, rather than char* (I also haven't found an easy way of converting "anything" to char* and then concatenating the two or more strings):

```
writeLog ("HydroMonitorECSensor::setCalibration  Receiving calibration - haveCalibration = " + String(haveCalibration));
writeLog ("HydroMonitorECSensor::setCalibration  calibratedSlope = " + String(calibratedSlope));
writeLog ("HydroMonitorECSensor::setPins  capPos set to " + String(capPos));
```

Where `haveCalibration` is a `bool` (which as String becomes either "true" or "false"), `calibratedSlope` is a `double` and `capPos` is an `int`. This way I can easily and cleanly send complete lines to the logger. Works great within the main script - not from the class.

I tried simply changing the `char*` to `String` and adding `#include <string.h>` to the library files but it doesn't work.

In Test.cpp I then get `void Test::setLogging (void (*f)(String) ) {` and in Test.h `void setLogging(void (*)(String));` and now I get error messages:

```
In file included from /home/wouter/Arduino/libraries/Test/Test.cpp:1:0:
/home/wouter/Arduino/libraries/Test/Test.h:10:29: error: expected ',' or '...' before '(' token
     void setLogging(void (*)(String)); // Takes function setting where to log.
                             ^
/home/wouter/Arduino/libraries/Test/Test.cpp:16:40: error: variable or field 'setLogging' declared void
 void Test::setLogging (void (*f)(String) ) {
                                        ^
/home/wouter/Arduino/libraries/Test/Test.cpp:16:31: error: 'f' was not declared in this scope
 void Test::setLogging (void (*f)(String) ) {
                               ^
/home/wouter/Arduino/libraries/Test/Test.cpp:16:34: error: 'String' was not declared in this scope
 void Test::setLogging (void (*f)(String) ) {
                                  ^
exit status 1
Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).
```

Suggestions?

Additional info, maybe important: I'm using the Arduino IDE and compile for ESP8266.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the Arduino-provided `String` class, but didn't include the `Arduino.h` header in your `test.h` header file. That causes it to not find the `String` class and compilation fails.

The following works:

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <test.hpp>

void writeLog (char* message);
void writeLog (String message);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Test t;
  t.setLogging(writeLog);
  writeLog("Test message!" + String(" .... "));
  t.doSomething("This is useful.");
  t.doSomething("This as well.\n");
  t.doSomething("This is even more useful.\n");
  bool b = true;

}

void loop() {
}

void writeLog (char* message) {
  Serial.print("char function: ");
  Serial.print(message);
}

void writeLog (String message) {
  Serial.print("String function: ");
  Serial.println(message);
}
```

`test.hpp`:

```
#ifndef TEST_h
#define TEST_h

#include <Arduino.h> //for "String" class

//Typdef for the log function. Takes a String, returns nothing
typedef void (*LogFunction)(String);

class Test
{
  public:
    Test();       // The constructor.
  //  void setLogging(void (*)(char*)); // Takes function setting where to log.
    void setLogging(LogFunction); //use the typedef here
    void doSomething(char*);
};

#endif
```

`test.cpp`:

```
#include <test.hpp>


LogFunction writeLog;

Test::Test () {
}

void Test::doSomething (char* s) {

  // Do something useful and log the result.
  writeLog(s);
}

//void Test::setLogging (void (*f)(char*) ) {
void Test::setLogging (LogFunction f) { //also use typedef here
  writeLog = f;
  return;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works! I actually did try to add the Arduino.h include before but must have done something else wrong, as it didn't work. In my main sketch I also don't have that include yet it still compiles, never needed this Arduino.h,  don't know how that works... Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Come to think of it, I maybe didn't try to include `Arduino.h`, not too sure as I tried a lot and got totally frustrated in the end trying this and that and nothing worked, but I for sure did try to include `string.h`. The latter is after all what I need in my normal sketches to be able to use the `String` types.

Answer (score 0):

Among other things that may arise, the compiler tells you that it cannot resolve identifier `String`.
This can have several reasons: First, you write `String`, and not `string` (note the capital letter in your writing). Second, if you write `string` and not `std::string`, it cannot be resolved unless you have either declared `using namespace std` (which is not the preferred variant for several reasons) or `using std::string`. Third, class `std::string` is declared in header `<string>`, which is something different than `<string.h>`.

So I'd write `#include <string>` and use then `std::string`.

Comment: This uses the Arduino `String` class, not a `std::string`.

Comment: That is a difference between standard C/C++ and Arduino (the posted code compiles fine in Arduino IDE). String is the Arduino version, std::string is the C version and the two are not compatible. I actually tried std::string and didn't get it to work.

Comment: @Maximilian Gerhardt: OK; I thought OP targeted the c++-string class. +1 for having pointed this out. BTW: why wouldn't std::string not work?

Comment: Not too sure why it didn't work. Part of the problem is probably that I ended up mixing two types with near-identical names, near-identical includes (`string` vs `string.h`), etc. That's of course asking for trouble. Conversion of the various types to `std::string` also doesn't look that straightforward as it is with `String`.